# Is there an equivalent of mat.Pow for CDense in Gonum?

Tags: go, gonum

given

```
a := mat.NewCDense(1,3, []complex128{
      1, 1 + 2i, 0.2
})
```

I would like to compute the power of 2 of each element in the matrix. Is there a method for mat.CDense equivalent to mat.Pow for mat.Dense?